# Fetch the latest 2 extreme subfolders from s3 bucket using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a s3 bucket which has multiple integrations.

I want to read the files from the latest 2 extreme subfolders.

[image]

I want to read all files from 2023/1/30/ and 2023/1/31/

```
import boto3

bucket_name = 'Bucket'
prefix = 'Facebook/Ad/'


s3_conn = boto3.client("s3")

response = s3_conn.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)


objects = sorted(response['Contents'], key=lambda x: x['LastModified'], reverse=True)

for obj in objects[:2]:
    subfolder = obj['Key']
    print(f"Subfolder: {subfolder}")
```

But this gives me the latest 2 files from the last subfolder:

```
2023/1/31/file12
2023/1/31/file13
```

How Can I read all files from the last 2 subfolders? Also, I do want to hard code things as the level of subfolders might increase. I need to find some how the latest 2 subfolders at the deepest level and fetch all files from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly get the list of common prefixes that with some feature like "latest object" you will need to enumerate all of the objects.  This can be done with simply enough with `list_objects_v2`, however each call to `list_objects_v2` is limited to returning 1000 objects.

Boto3 provides a helper, called [Paginators](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) that does the work for you of calling APIs like this multiple times with the proper parameters to work through all of the pages.

Since your goal is to get a list of all objects that share two common prefixes, it makes sense to keep the complete list of objects as you encounter them, then you can operate on the list as desired after you've determined which two common prefixes are interesting.

Putting it together, the code to do this would look something like this:

```python
import boto3
from collections import defaultdict
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

# Build a list of all common prefixes, with their objects
common_prefixes = defaultdict(list)
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name):
    for cur in page.get('Contents', []):
        common_prefix = "/".join(cur['Key'].split("/")[:-1])
        # Store the information broken out by common prefix
        common_prefixes[common_prefix].append(cur)

# Turn the dictionary into a simple list of common prefixes and objects
common_prefixes = [(k, v) for k, v in common_prefixes.items()]
# Sort by the max last modified date in each prefix
common_prefixes.sort(key=lambda x: max(y['LastModified'] for y in x[1]))

# And now show information on the two most recent common prefixes
for common_prefix, objects in common_prefixes[-2:]:
    print(f"----- Prefix: {common_prefix} -----")
    # Just show the objects in a format somewhat like "aws s3 ls"
    for cur in objects:
        print(f"{cur['LastModified'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')} {cur['Size']:10d} {cur['Key']}")
```

It should be noted that doing this will take time and memory for very large buckets, not to mention API calls.  If have a very large bucket with millions of objects, you should consider setting up an [S3 inventory report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) so you can pull down a single object to get a list of objects, or if the prefixes follow a predictable pattern, use a few calls to [`list_objects_v2` with the `Delimiter` flag](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html), still via the Paginator, to directly find the prefixes and operate on them directly without querying for metadata on the objects.

Comment: I just noticed you were 3 points shy of 10k and upvoted this answer. Congratulations!