# Getting the oldest subfolder names from a large S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I scoured the site for all `aws s3` related questions but could not find the answer.

I have a s3 bucket `s3://large-bucket` and in it there are subfolders with unique names structured as `user=<user_id>/...`. Then inside each `user` subfolder, there are subfolders by year, month and day. So the list of  full URIs for one example user with `id = 12345` would look like:

```
s3://large-bucket/user=12345/2020/12/25
s3://large-bucket/user=12345/2020/12/26
...
s3://large-bucket/user=12345/2023/11/07
```

if the earliest date of data for this user is `2020/12/25` and a new subfolder for the current day is created daily. In each of these nested subfolders live the actual data. What I want to do is to get the **earliest date** for each user in the `large-bucket`. So the output I want could be a json/dictionary like :

```
{....
 ....
'12345' : '2020/12/25'
 ....
}
```

I have no interest in the data - only this earliest date for each user. So far, everything I looked up includes some version of downloading/syncing folders and this is infeasible as my bucket is huge and there are tens of thousands of users, each of which on average has 5+ years of data (so at least 1800 subfolders for each users.)

What is a quick way to achieve this ? Any solution that downloads the data will take too long for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the latest 2 extreme subfolders from s3 bucket using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77271900/fetch-the-latest-2-extreme-subfolders-from-s3-bucket-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to solve this by making direct API calls to S3 to list subfolders. Especially since folders [don't even exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77135544/13070) in S3, they are just prefixes for object names.

Given that you have a huge number of objects/prefixes in your S3 bucket, the best way to solve this problem is going to be to have Amazon create an [S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) for you. Once you do that, and wait for it to complete, you can either download the inventory file and pull out the values you need via a script that you write, or you could leave the inventory file in an S3 bucket and run queries against it using  [Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html).